# Extracting user details from SMS messages in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, token, text-mining

I ve a dataset of mobile SMSs, specifically I want to extract certain details like data balance, date of expiry using R, I ve done the tokenization using NLP and regex, but the thing is I cannot extract the date if the SMS format is something like given below:
**Your 46.35 MB data will expire on 2017-02-08.Buy any of the data plans to continue enjoying the service. Text HELP to 229 for more information.**
Notice that there is no space between 2017-02-08, period(.) and buy, so while tokenizing R treats it as a single token. If I replace period with a space then extracting the data amount(46.35 MB) would become difficult.
Can anyone pls suggest if I can use some text modelling or train the machine to extract these details even if the format of the SMS changes with time
**My SMSs format(structure) would differ. So can I train the dataset?how to proceed?**
My output should be
Data balance, expiry date along with other details going forward in future.

Comment: Don't rely on a default tokenization. Just craft a custom regex for this particular case. You can capture dates which are immediately followed by a period. If these things have a specified format, then it really isn't `nlp`.

Comment: but I ve a dozen other formats where the language(structure) might change, like the date might be followed by some other character/word
@JohnColeman

Comment: So, what have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: Non-standardized formats are a pain to work with (which is one of the main reasons that things like dates and phone-numbers are such a hassle when programming) but that still doesn't make it a natural language processing problem -- which is good news. Doing something like training a neural network to extract the relevant information would be much harder than coming up with a dozen regular expressions.

Comment: I ve tokenized the text into units, ran a basic regex to find the date objects using anytime() , further I extracted the data balance left using regex operator, I was wondering if there was a better way to do it, because as mentioned dates in certain formats won't be recognized. Further when my SMS structure would change I ve to revamp the whole code. How can I use neural network here? Because I am kinda new to text mining @JohnColeman

Comment: Simple tokenization and putting the token vector under regex to extract dates, but certain formats of dates are not recognized here, next is if the SMS structure changes it would be very hard to extract other details. Can you suggest an alternative here? @RomanLuštrik

Comment: @karunSingla Did you find any way out of this. I am also looking for same problem

Comment: anyone has a suggestion for this, I am also trying to solve a similar problem now.